# How do I parse a root JSON Array with restassured?

Tags: json, rest-assured

I see that I can do the following with restassured.  Given JSON:

```
{"locationId"=456,"name"="Home"}
```

I can get an object representing that json like this:

```
Location location = given().headers(headers).when().expect().statusCode(200).get(getUrl(urlQualifier)).as(Location.class);
```

How do I parse this JSON is I receive a root array of my Location objects in JSON.  So, given this JSON:

```
[{"locationId"=1,name="Home"},{"locationId"=2,name="Work"}]
```

I want to parse out a List object.  The following of course is a compile error, but it demonstrates what I am trying to do:

```
List<Location> list = given().headers(headers).when().expect().statusCode(200).get(getUrl(urlQualifier)).as((List<Location>).class);
```

Comment: your format for json is not correct :

Comment: `{locationId=456,name="Home"}` is not valid JSON. This is: `{"locationId":456,"name":"Home"}`.

Answer (score 3):

Try deserializing it to a Java array:

```
Location[] list = given().headers(headers).when().expect().statusCode(200).get(getUrl(urlQualifier)).as(Location[].class);
```